# MySQL Dynamically Merge/Select Select Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I just need some direction on this.  I have the following tables:

```
Table: entity
 - ID (INT)

Table: attributes
 - ID (INT)
 - name (VARCHAR)
 - internalname (VARCHAR)

Table: values
 - ID (INT)
 - entity (ID)
 - attributes (INT)
 - value (Text)
```

What I want is to make a Select statment that will return something like the following:

```
 - ID = entity.ID
 - {attributes.internalname ID 1} = values.{attribe internalname 1}.value
 - {attributes.internalname ID 2} = values.{attribe internalname 2}.value
 - {attributes.internalname ID 3} = values.{attribe internalname 3}.value
 - {attributes.internalname ID n} = values.{attribe internalname n}.value
 - etc...
```

It would be like combining:

```
SELECT entity.id FROM entity;
```

and

```
SELECT (SELECT values.value FROM values WHERE values.entity = entity.ID AND values.attributes = attributes.ID) FROM attributes;
```

It is a difficult thing to explain, however if you need me to explain further, please let me know.

I effectively want to rotate all values in attributes to columns and turn all the values into its corresponding attribute's value with the ID as the selector.

I give the query an ID (The element ID), and in one result row it returns all the data.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I do not see why the table entity exists with only one column, that is already stored in the values table

Comment: It is just as an index, and a few columns may appear there. This is actually very similar to how Magento Commerce stores it's data, problem is that they use hundreds of queries to get this same result I am trying to achieve in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create columns dynamically, so you need to know beforehand what you want as columns.

If attributes (1,2,3,4) represent (firstname, lastname, extraname, additionalname) you can query it like this:

```
select e.id
      ,v1.value as firstname
      ,v2.value as lastname
      ,v3.value as extraname
      ,v4.value as additionalname
  from entity e
  left join values v1 on(e.id = v1.entity and v1.attributes = 1)
  left join values v2 on(e.id = v2.entity and v2.attributes = 2)
  left join values v3 on(e.id = v3.entity and v3.attributes = 3)
  left join values v4 on(e.id = v4.entity and v4.attributes = 4)
 where e.id = ?
```

or

```
select e.id
      ,max(case when v.attributes = 1 then value) as firstname
      ,max(case when v.attributes = 2 then value) as lastname
      ,max(case when v.attributes = 3 then value) as extraname
      ,max(case when v.attributes = 4 then value) as additionalname
  from entity e
  left join values v on(e.id = v.entity)
 where v.attributes in(1,2,3,4)
   and e.id = ?
 group by e.id;
```

You can also use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to return the values in a comma separated list  in one column.

```
select e.id
      ,group_concat(v.value)
  from entity e
  left join values v on(e.id = v.entity)
 group 
    by e.id;
```

Oh, and `values` is a reserved word. Don't use it as table name.

Oh 2, don't use this model unless you really really have to. You will pay a big juicy price in terms of performance and data consistency.

Comment: You Rock! Thanks man! What model would you advise for data storage then? This is just a generic model I was planning on using for different elements of a system...

Answer (score 0):

**I do not condone selecting * so replace with your columns. Values may be a reserved keyword**

```
   select * 
   from values v

   left join attributes a
     on a.id = v.attributes

   left join entity e
     on e.id = v.entity

   where 1=1

   /* put your where clause here */
```

Comment: That is very close to what I wany, however I would like all the data back in one row.  I updated my original post.
Thanks though!